# Convert picture to B&W with specific rules

Tags: python, image, image-manipulation

I am trying to analyze a picture. I am basically doing that in 2 steps:

1. converting it into a greyscale picture
2. taking areas in the picture and look if they are more likely white or black

My program works quite well in most cases but not all. That is mainly because I never really understood, how to convert the picture into black and white. I mainly copied code I found and made it work with trial and error(that's why I ended up, with greyscale and not b/w, since I didn't find, how to make every non-white pixel in the greyscale to black)

I am using PIL for my picture operations and my main functions for the picture operating look like this(convert() is used once and avgcol() is used for every part of the converted picture, I want to analyze)

```
def convert():
    global im   
    matrix = (1.412453, 0.357580, 0.180423, 0,
           0.212671, 0.715160, 0.072169, 0,
           0.019334, 0.119193, 0.950227, 0 )
    im = im.convert("L", matrix)

def avgcol(im):
    p_colors=im.getcolors()
    cnt_pix=(im.size[0])*(im.size[1])
    avgpix=0
    for i in range(len(p_colors)):
        avgpix=avgpix+p_colors[i][0]*p_colors[i][1]
    return round(avgpix/cnt_pix  , 1)
```

I do not really know, what the matrix does(didn't find a site, which explains the single values).
My specific problem right now, is that I'd like to convert pixels with too much green into white pixels, but I am pretty sure, that if that is solved, something else pops out, so some basic explaining, how something like that is done, would be great.
But I am thankful for any pointer in the right direction. 
And please no solution with for-looping every pixel. The pictures are pretty big and the program should be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515191701id_/http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), you'll see a few things.

First, `convert` has a one-argument version, which only takes a `mode`.

If you just want an RGB-to-greyscale conversion:

```
grey = im.convert("L")
```

The only reason to provide a matrix is if you don't want to use the default transformation.

And you can also convert directly to bilevel black&white:

```
bw = im.convert("1")
```

As the docs say:

> When converting to a bilevel image (mode "1"), the source image is first converted to black and white. Resulting values larger than 127 are then set to white, and the image is dithered. To use other thresholds, use the point method.

So, if you want the standard threshold and dithering, just `convert`. If you want a different threshold, it looks like this:

```
grey = im.convert("L")
table = [int(i>200) for i in range(256)]
bw = grey.point(table, '1')
```

---

In your answer, you say:

> … how to make every non-white pixel in the greyscale to black

If you really mean "anything other than absolute pure white" as "non-white", you can't use `point` for that. Even if you `convert` to `L16` and `point` with a 65536-item table, that can't distinguish between 99.998% and 100% white, and it's conceivable that some of your original pixels that weren't white get matched wrong. So for that, you probably want to just iterate the original pixels directly (with the `load` function) and build a new image manually.

---

As for what the matrix does… that's pretty simple if you understand the basics of matrix math. (If you don't, I can't explain it here, but [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) may be a good starting place.)

Treat each source pixel as a vector (e.g., in an RGBA image, the vector `<red, green, blue, alpha>`. Multiply that vector by a matrix, and you get a new vector. Treat that as a pixel in the destination colorspace.

For example, if you have D65 RGBA pixels, and you multiply each one by the 4x3 matrix given in the docs, the results are CIE XYZ pixels.

This means there is no reason to use a 4x3 matrix to convert to L. What you want is a 4x1 matrix. And then, only if you don't want the default. As the docs say:

> When from a colour image to black and white, the library uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform:

```
L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000
```

… which is just `(.299, .587, .114, 0)`.

---

So, if you want to:

> convert pixels with too much green into white pixels

That's somewhat ambiguous. But at least one way to do something like that is to just overemphasize the green. For example, if you use `(.1495, .8448 , .0057, 0)`, green will be counted a lot more than usual (and red and blue a lot less) for determining brightness.

---

Meanwhile, at the end of your question:

> And please no solution with for-looping every pixel. The pictures are pretty big and the program should be fast.

Under the covers, of course, a PIL command like `bw = grey.point([int(i>200) for i in range(256)], '1')` is actually for-looping every pixel in `grey`. It's just doing the loop in C rather than Python. And you can do the same thing yourself with [Cython](http://www.cython.org), or do it implicitly with [numpy](http://numpy.org), or just use [PyPy](http://pypy.org) instead of your existing Python interpreter (which can JIT your Python for loop up to almost C speed).

Why would you want to do that? Well, look at the thresholding code each way:

```
# PIL
table = [int(i>200) for i in range(256)]
bw = grey.point(table, '1')

# Python (run in PyPy) or Cython
bw = [pixel > 200 for pixel in grey]

# numpy
bw = grey > 200
```

Comment: thanks, that gave me some ideas. I still don't understand all of what you said, but it gave me some hints to try stuff out.
I looked some more into the RGB-values and I just realized, that green doesn't really matter. Blue is the color when overpresented should be turned black.
After some tries, the solution that works best is
def convert():
    global im   
    matrix = (1, 1, -1, 100)
    table = [int(i>250) for i in range(256)]
    im = im.convert("L", matrix).point(table, '1')
still, I don't understand what alpha means, wikipedia says it is transparency but that doesn't make sense here

Comment: @user2179887: In a picture that doesn't have any transparency, `alpha` is always 100% (that is, `1.0` if you're using floats, `255` for 8-bit ints, `65535` for 16-bit ints), and you don't need to worry about it. If the picture _does_ have transparency, then `alpha` is 0% for fully transparent pixels, 100% for fully opaque, and in-between for partially-see-through pixels.

Comment: after some testing I realized that i can use the alpha-value to make the greyscale darker or lighter. that means that im.convert("L", (1, 1, -1, -50) ).point([int(i>100) for i in range(256)], '1') is the same as im.convert("L", (1, 1, -1, 0) ).point([int(i>150) for i in range(256)], '1').
I thought that im.point([int(i>127) for i in range(256)], '1') is the same as im.convert('1') but that doesn't seem to be true. I could use that to remove the whole point-operation, but this two operations seem to work in completly different ways. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2179887: Yes, as long as the source alpha is always 100% (it has no transparency), you can use it as a constant additive term like that. But why? For anything but thresholding, you almost always want multiplication, not addition. And for thresholding, as you already say, you can just adjust the threshold.

Comment: @user2179887: Meanwhile, `convert('1')` thresholds at 127 (like your `.point` call) _and_ applies a default dithering algorithm.

Comment: ok, I found out that you can use dither=0 in convert, to disable the dither effect. you are not the first one, who tells me that point is slow, so I thought using the alpha as threshould and convert('1') would be faster, but it's already fast enough anyway, so I should just leave it. (I used a for-loop in python for the pixels in an earlier version and that was really slow, but if there is a for-loop in C, that is fast enough, it's ok for me)

Comment: @user2179887: Out of curiosity, did you use a for loop around `getpixel()`? Because if so, that's up to an order of magnitude slower than calling `load()` and doing a for loop around the resulting array (which is itself an order of magnitude or two slower than letting PIL or numpy do the looping for you in C).

Comment: I used it, to get the color of every pixel, but then I found out, about getcolors()(like in my second function mentioned aboive), changing that, changed the runtime of on analyze cycle from 2 sec to something below half a second

Comment: @user2179887: Well, `getcolors` returns a histogram of all of the colors in the image. So, if you have 4M pixels, but only 1K distinct colors, you end up iterating 4M loops in C but only 1K loops in Python, which is obviously faster. But it also does something completely _different_. If you _do_ need to get the color of every pixel, `getcolors` won't help. But what _will_ help is replacing `getpixel` with `load`—you still have to loop 4M times, but you're reducing the cost of each iteration by… in 3 quick tests, it may be 2x, 4x, or 12x (not sure what causes the difference).